# SQL Computed Column Formula Syntax

Tags: sql, calculated-columns

I have 3 columns in table name CONTROLLER:

CONTROLLER_ID int, CONTROLLER varchar(10) and VID,

I wanted VID Column to be a calculated column and this syntax works as a query but not when I enter into the Computed Column Formula

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN (CONTROLLER = 'Intel') THEN '666' WHEN (CONTROLLER = 'Mellanox')    
           THEN '777' 
         ELSE '888' 
       END AS VID FROM CONTROLLER
```

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: And what exactly does "enter into the computed column formula" mean? Enter where? Enter what? What was the error message? What was the SQL statement that you tried for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following create table statement works fine for me on MS Sql Server 2017:

```
CREATE TABLE CONTROLLER (
  CONTROLLER VARCHAR(10),
  VID AS CASE 
    WHEN (CONTROLLER = 'Intel') THEN '666' 
    WHEN (CONTROLLER = 'Mellanox') THEN '777' 
    ELSE '888' 
  END
)
```

Comment: Thank you Jonas.. That did it for me.